# Transfer Minecraft over Google Accounts

Tags: android, minecraft-bedrock-edition, google-play-games

I bought Minecraft on my Google account, but my son wants to use it on his Google account. Is that possible? I bought it on my account, so I'm unsure.

Comment: Minecraft has nothing to do with any Google accounts, so this question makes no sense.

Comment: @FabianRöling OP probably bought on Android using Google Play Store.

Comment: Indeed, bought on Android using Google play

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't play a game that was bought on one account, unless you enable "Family Sharing" in the account settings of your Google account, and then add his account to the "Family", and then he should be able to re-download it from the play store on his device.

Comment: This uses the [tag:minecraft] tag, so it's not MCPE.

Comment: eh? idk wym pal

Comment: What? What do any of these three character abbreviations mean?